# Opening a Chrome extension as a pop-up using a link

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension installed in my browser.  When I click the extension's icon in the menu bar the extension opens as a floating pop-up, as expected.

What I am trying to do is to open the extension in Chrome via a link/shortcut/whatever from another program.  As a first step I've tried opening the extension from the command line, ex:
chrome "chrome-extension://abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/index.html"

This works but the extension opens as a new tab and takes up a full broswer page instead of a just being a pop-up.  Is there a way to open the extension as a pop-up on top of any open tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it's completely impossible.

There is [an API in the works](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489), but it would require at a minimum a user gesture, at a maximum explicit invocation of the extension.

So opening a link would not be enough, nor would a Native Message be.

Answer (score 0):

you cant make the native extension  popup to show programatically but you could use a content script that displays the popup (using the new  for example) on the tab that you want.